# How do you reference a variable from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a common question and I've looked for answers that I'd actually understand for an hour and half but still no progress. It's really simple; in one class, I have a public float variable:

```
public class SlowOnLongGrass : MonoBehaviour
public float speed;
```

And in another class I have :

```
public class SlowOnLongGrass : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Long grass")
        {
            PlayerMovement.speed -= 2f;
```

My aim : when the player walks over "long grass" reduce the speed by 2f and when the person leaves the long grass, put the speed back to its original position. However I get an error saying

"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'PlayerMovement.speed"

Please give a simple explanation I can understand of why my code isn't working, thanks.

my playerMovement class :

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sprite Up;
    public Sprite Down;
    public Sprite Right;
    public Sprite Left;
    public float speed;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 move;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Up;
            move = new Vector2(0, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.position += move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Left;
            move = new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            transform.position -= move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Right;
            move = new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            transform.position += move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Down;
            move = new Vector2(0,speed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.position -= move;
        }
```

Comment: OK, imagine you leave your wallet in your friend's red 2012 Honda Civic and he drives away. So you go to the Honda dealership and break into the first green 2019 Honda Civic you see on the lot. What are the chances your wallet will be in that car? Zero. It's a different car. "Honda Civic" isn't enough information to find YOUR wallet. So also with PlayerMovement: You need to tell the compiler which **instance** of PlayerMovement you want. Tell us more about your code and we can help you figure that out. Do you have a `PlayerMovement` class? Did you create an instance of it anywhere?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Nice analogy. I just added my `PlayerMovement` class to my question.

Answer (score 3):

`speed` is a **non-static** field of `PlayerMovement`. This it requires a specific **instance** of `PlayerMovement` in order to change this value for that specific instance.

---

What you are trying currently is setting it directly through the type `PlayerMovent`. This would only be allowed **if** `speed` **was**

```
public static float speed;
```

However this would make this value being "shared" between all instances of `PlayerMovement`. It might fix your issue but is actually a dirty workarounds!

---

What you rather need and want to do is an instance reference. In Unity this is most of the time done using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html). As this is quite slow you should call it as little as possible. In your case you could probably even configure it already in the Inspector:

```
// Reference it via the inspector
// This will store the reference to the PlayerMovement Component instance
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement playerMovement;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Or get it on runtime
    if(!playerMovement) playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    // I also strongly recommend using CompareTag
    // It is slightly faster and additionally throws an error
    // if an invalid tag is passed -> more secure and better to debug
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Long grass")
    {
        playerMovement.speed -= 2f;
    }
}
```

depending on your hierarchy structure you might have to use [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) or [`GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html) if the collider is not attached to the same GameObject as the script.

---

As this is one of the most basic things for coding in Unity I strongly recommend to either do better research or/and go through the [Beginners Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials)

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation and corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm not getting any errors now. I'm just not sure what I'm referencing through the inspector. Currently, the code is attached to the long grasses in my project and my player sprite still isn't slowing down when it goes over it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling you are not quite getting what an Instance of a class is.

When you define a class for example:

```
public class Example {
    int someValue = 5;
}
```

You can't just say Example.someValue, because a class definition is like a mold for making objects. You need an object that is of class A in order to get the value.

```
Example classInstance = new Example();
```

When you do this, you have created an object called classInstance and then u can get the value

```
classInstance.SomeValue
```

Now, you can do what you are tring with something called static fields but i kind of dont think that would help here as i would probably throw you off.

Comment: In Unity you can't use `new` to create an instance. Components Instantiated either via the Editor or by using `AddComponent`